# grub rescue after windows updations mediated

Tags: 12.04

yesterday my windows 8 automatically started upgrading to 8.1.i cancelled it in between by shutting of my laptop.Now my original window is restored but Ubuntu that was installed within it does  not run.it shows grub rescue.please help soon.v urgent

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tool it has helped many computers: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair